# Overriding datasource of a hibernate sessionfactory in test cases

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, unit-testing, sessionfactory

I have a hibernate SessionFactoryBean configured in my applicationContext which already has a real datasource as property. But i would like to use another local/mock datasource in my test class by overriding the actual datasource which was already injected to the sessionfactory.

The bean definition in the main application Context is like this.

```
<bean id="SessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean"
            abstract="false" scope="singleton" lazy-init="default" autowire="default">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="pcfDataSource"/>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">$`db.hibernate.dialect}   </prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
</bean>
```

I have a local datasource like this in my test case:

```
template = InitializeDataSource.getInitializedDataSource();
DataSource dataSource = template.getDataSource;
```

I need to override the injected datasource with the one in the bottom

Comment: You could look at using java profiles.

Answer (score 1):

You can use profiles if your spring version is 3.1 or newer: 
Put your bean declaration inside a beans tag with profile

```
<beans profile="!test">
     <bean id="pcfDataSource" ...>
          ...
     </bean>
</beans>
```

Then in your test class you add "test" as your active profile

```
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = "app-context.xml")
public class SampleTest
```

Finally you add your datasource configuration in the end of your test class

```
@Test
public void someTest() {
     ...
}

@Configuration
public class MockDataSourceConfig {
    @Bean
    public DataSource pcfDataSource() {
        Template template = InitializeDataSource.getInitializedDataSource();
        return template.getDataSource; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Gargarao, thanks for the response, but I need a session factory with an overridden datasource, I think this just returns me a datasource

Comment: My bad! I edited showing how to profile the datasource. That way when spring looks for the bean to inject inside the session factory it will get the one configured in the test class